# Shiny interactive click return shifted coords after plot modification

Tags: r, plot, shiny, interactive

I try to modify a plot with adding a second x-axis on the top of the plot in Shiny. However, interactive clicks end up with shifted coords return. I'm wondering if there is correct method to get the correct click returns, that is, click on subject's column on the plot will return the print-out of all data for that patients.

```
library(shiny)

## generate data
for (i in 1:19){
  ID = sprintf("%02d", i)
  Fail =sprintf("%03d", round(runif(1,0,300)))
  Score = runif(4,-3,3)
  di = data.frame(ID=ID,Class=LETTERS[1:4],Score=Score,Fail=Fail)
  if (i==1) dta=di
  else dta=rbind(dta,di)
}
dta$Type = "Tag2"
dta$Type[dta$Class %in% c("A","D")] = "Tag1"

thm <- theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.title.align=0.1,
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, angle = 90, hjust = 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
 fluidRow(
  column(7,
       plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot1_click")
 ),
 column(4,
       br(), br(), br(),
       htmlOutput("x_value"),
       verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows")
))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

 P1 <- ggplot(dta, aes(ID, Class)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Score), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("navyblue", "white","red")) + 
  ylab("Class") + xlab("List of subjects") + 
  labs(fill = "Score \nLevel") + 
  thm  +
  facet_grid(Type~.,scales="free_y", space="free_y",labeller=labeller(Type = label_wrap_gen(10))) +
  theme( panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "lines"),   strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(0, "cm"),
         panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), 
         strip.background =element_rect(fill="lightblue",color="black",size=1))+
         scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))

P2 <- ggplot(dta, aes(Fail, Class)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Score), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("navyblue", "white","red")) + 
  ylab("Class") + xlab("Subjects' Failure") + 
  labs(fill = "Score \nLevel") + 
  thm  +
  facet_grid(Type~.,scales="free_y", space="free_y",labeller=labeller(Type = label_wrap_gen(10))) +
  theme( panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "lines"),   strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(0, "cm"),
         panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), 
         strip.background =element_rect(fill="lightblue",color="black",size=1))+
         scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))

g1 <- ggplotGrob(P1)    
g2 <- ggplotGrob(P2)

## Get the position of the plot panel in g1
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel-1-1", se = t:r))

vinvert_title_grob <- function(grob) {
  heights <- grob$heights
  grob$heights[1] <- heights[3]
  grob$heights[3] <- heights[1]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$heights[1] <- heights[3]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$heights[3] <- heights[1]

  grob$children[[1]]$hjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$hjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$vjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$vjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$y <- unit(1, "npc") - grob$children[[1]]$y
  grob
}

# Copy "Elevation (ft)" xlab from g2 and swap margins
index <- which(g2$layout$name == "xlab-b")
xlab <- g2$grobs[[index]]
xlab <- vinvert_title_grob(xlab)

# Put xlab at the top of g1
g1 <- gtable_add_rows(g1, g2$heights[g2$layout[index, ]$t], pp$t-1)
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, xlab, pp$t, pp$l, pp$t, pp$r, clip = "off", name="topxlab")

# Get "feet" axis (axis line, tick marks and tick mark labels) from g2
index <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-b-1")
xaxis <- g2$grobs[[index]]

# Move the axis line to the bottom (Not needed in your example)
xaxis$children[[1]]$y <- unit.c(unit(0, "npc"), unit(0, "npc"))

# Swap axis ticks and tick mark labels
ticks <- xaxis$children[[2]]
ticks$heights <- rev(ticks$heights)
ticks$grobs <- rev(ticks$grobs)

# Move tick marks
ticks$grobs[[2]]$y <- ticks$grobs[[2]]$y - unit(1, "npc") + unit(3, "pt")

# Sswap tick mark labels' margins
ticks$grobs[[1]] <- vinvert_title_grob(ticks$grobs[[1]])

# Put ticks and tick mark labels back into xaxis
xaxis$children[[2]] <- ticks

# Add axis to top of g1
g1 <- gtable_add_rows(g1, g2$heights[g2$layout[index, ]$t], pp$t)
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, xaxis, pp$t+1, pp$l, pp$t+1, pp$r, clip = "off", name = "axis-t")

#pa = dual_xaxis(data=dta)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
})

# Print the name of the x value
output$x_value <- renderText({
 if (is.null(input$plot1_click$x)) return("")
 else {
  lvls <- levels(dta$ID)
  name <- lvls[round(input$plot1_click$x)]
  HTML("You've selected <code>", name, "</code>",
       "<br><br>Here are socres that ",
       "match the selection:")
  }
})

# Print the rows of the data frame which match the x value
output$selected_rows <- renderPrint({
 if (is.null(input$plot1_click$x)) return()
  else {
  keeprows <- round(input$plot1_click$x) == as.numeric(dta$ID)
  head(dta[keeprows, ])
  }
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Use the above code, I need to click up to relative position of subject 12 to get returns like the following:

```
  ID Class      Score Fail Type
1 01     A  0.1547077  229 Tag1
2 01     B -2.7327629  229 Tag2
3 01     C -1.0500660  229 Tag2
4 01     D -0.9531061  229 Tag1
```